# How to get href from h3 Selenium/Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

URL: https://www.piie.com/research/economic-issues/coronavirus

I am trying to pull hrefs from class "field field--title" but my coding is not working

```
driver.get('https://www.piie.com/research/economic-issues/coronavirus')

for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('field field--title'):
    for a in i.find_elements_by_css_selector('a'):
        print(a.get_attribute('href'))
        print(a.text)
```

HTML is showing below:

[image]

Can anyone help me with the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait elements to appear in the web page before trying to get something from them. For that Selenium has Implicit and Explicit wait solutions. You can find very good information about both waits [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and [here](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver).

In the code below I used explicit wait for elements to be visible to be able to get text from them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    driver.get('https://www.piie.com/research/economic-issues/coronavirus')

    items = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.field--title a')))
    for item in items:
        print(item.text, item.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to know if wait.until() is always required when using Selenium to parse the URL?

Comment: I use it in 99.99%

Comment: Thanks! One last question, does the explicit wait better than the implicit wait? or there is no difference to use.

Comment: Much more useful